# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException with wp8 sdk

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, windows-phone-8

I have just begun developing wp8 apps ( No prior experience). Was just starting with this :

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-3-Writing-your-First-Windows-Phone-8-App

Proceeded exactly as shown, and got this :

**"A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."**

Code:

(Default code with foll. additions) :

```
private void PlayAudioButton_Click_1 (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        QuackMediaElement.Play();
    }
```

and default xaml with foll. additions :

```
<Button Name="PlayAudioButton"
                Width="200"
                Height="200 "
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Background="Crimson"
                Click="PlayAudioButton_Click_1"
                >
            Quack

        </Button>

        <MediaElement x:Name="QuackMediaElement"
                      Source="/Assets/quack.mp3 "
                      Volume=" 1"
                      AutoPlay="False" 
                      />
```

What can it be ?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception probably occurs because of

```
Source="/Assets/quack.mp3 "
Volume=" 1"
```

instead of

```
Source="/Assets/quack.mp3"    
Volume="1"
```